# Як прочитати ЗНО?

Tags: фонетика, скорочення

Як правильно прочитати абревіатуву ***"ЗНО"***, окремо по буквах чи як ціле слово? Абревіатура ЗМІ читається як слово, а от СБУ — окремо по буквах. Не можу знайти відповідне правило.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Цитую з відео [Олександра Авраменка](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=92&v=CS0jzfuSn8M):

#### Є два підходи у вимовлянні абревіатур:

1. Одні абревіатури вимовляють як звуки. Читаємо їх як звичайне слово.
   Так робимо тоді, коли **всередині скороченої назви є голосний
   звук**.

Приклади: ЦУМ (читаємо як "цум"), ВАТ ("ват"), ЧАЕС ("чаес")

2. Якщо голосного всередині абревіатури немає, то вимовляють, називаючи
   кожну букву.

Приклади: МЗС ("ем-зе-ес"), СБУ ("ес-бе-у"),

3. Винятки: ЗМІ ("змі"), США ("сша") та деякі інші.

#### Висновок:

**ЗНО**

не містить всередині голосного звука, отже кожну літеру треба вимовляти окремо:

**зе-ен-о.**